# Unable to type vietnamese in visual studio code from ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, unicode, typing

I need to comment and text some Vietnamese words in Visual Studio Code but it doesn't work.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04, and I use the software Ibus Bamboo v0.6.6 to type Vietnamese.
Please help me.

Update: I have fixed this problem by reinstall VSCode by the file .deb.
reference this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: do you have permission to edit the file? check `file permision` user and group

Comment: Thanks you @csaw, i have fixed this problem! Because i install VSCode by Ubuntu Software, i just uninstall it and reinstall using the file deb;

Comment: I can verify that his solution works as expected.